# How to avoid select drop-downs going offscreen on smaller device

Tags: html, css, angular, drop-down-menu, responsive-design

I'm trying really hard to avoid the following scenario on smaller devices.
The dropdown box should not go out of screen.

Here is my html code:

```
<div class="form-group row">
      <label for="category" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Category</label>
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-6"> 
        <select col-sm-4style="width:100%" class="custom-select form-control" name="category" #cat (ngModelChange)='updateCategoryId(cat)' [(ngModel)]="form.category"
          #category="ngModel">
          <option class="col-sm-4" *ngFor="let type of categoryNames;let itemIndex = index" [selected]="itemIndex == 0" [value]="type.name"
            [id]="type.id">{{type.name}}</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
```

And the result looks like:
[image: dropdown offscreen screenshot]

I'm searching for a CSS-based way to avoid this.

Comment: "Smaller Devices" often mean smartphones. When running on a smartphone (not an emulator) does ist also go offscreen? iPhones (and android smartphones) have their own "implementation" of dropdown menus.

Comment: Thanks @Cijsters